# Google Cloud Endpoint and Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-endpoints

I defined a Google Cloud Endpoints that uses `Objectify` to deal with the datastore. The issue is that my model uses the objectify `com.googlecode.objectify.Key` class.

```java
@Entity
public class RealEstateProperty implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Parent
    private Key<Owner> owner;
    private String name;
    private Key<Address> address;

}
```

In my endpoint I defined a method to create a `RealEstateProperty`:

```java
@ApiMethod(name = "create", path = "properties", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public void create(RealEstateProperty property, User user) throws Exception {
    }
```

In the `API Explorer`, the `create` method expects a string representing a `Key` for the address. The issue is that I'd like to provide the address and not the `Key`.

Is it possible to create an endpoint with `objectify`? If so, how do you design your data model to deal with `Key`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class for communication via API (endpoint) that contain an address field instead Key field:

```
public class RealEstatePropertyAPI implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Key<Owner> owner;
    private String name;
    private Address address;

}
```

and in your endpoint:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "create", path = "properties", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public void create(RealEstatePropertyAPI propertyAPI, User user) throws Exception {
    //ie: get address from propertyAPI and find in datastore or create new one.
}
```

or just add another parameter to your endpoint.

Comment: This is what I tried first but it seems that `objectify` handles one-to-one relationship with a `Key` object. When I did not use the `Key`, I got an exception when saving the entity. `Address is not a supported type`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly but: 
1) for Multi-Value Relationship see this:
https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Multi-Value_Relationship

2) do not save RealEstatePropertyAPI get the address (and another data). Find in datastore given address and get it key or create new one, then just create new RealEstateProperty and fill data.

Comment: Ok I got it, so there is no way to use directly the `objectify` model. I have to use temporary object to get the data from the client and then convert them to the data model.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it seems endpoints don't support Objectify Keys. This caused a few issues for me too. To avoid the errors thrown in the maven build I annotated the Key property to be ignored by the Endpoint https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations:

```
 @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
```

When adding a new RealEstateProperty using your endpoint, create your Address object with a String argument in your endpoint. Pass your new Address object as an argument to your RealEstateProperty constructor and create and assign the key within the constructor.

```
@Entity
public class RealEstateProperty implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private Long id;
  @Parent
  private Key<Owner> owner;
  private String name;
  @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
  private Key<Address> address;

}
```